# add breakpoints for each line automatically in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I have a large project hundreds of classes and thousands of lines...

My goal is To debug whole application line by line but add a break points for each line manually can Take days. I wonder if there is a way to add break points for each line automatically ?

I am googling about this but can found anything

Answer (score 0):

Add breakpoint to line where you need to start debug.
And then use "Step Over F8", "Step Into F7" and "Step out Shift+F8" to move through programm line by line / into block/function / out of block.